# Get Form1 properties from class

Tags: c#, forms, reference

I want to be able to get Form1 properties from within a class. Properties such as Width, Left, WindowState, and so on. So that I can then do this in the class: *MessageBox.Show(Form1.Width);* So I want to reference the whole Form1. How do I do that in code?

Comment: Pass the `Form1` into the Class’s constructor? This sounds like an odd thing to do.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong... I want to be able to access Form1's properties from the class. Do this for example, from the class: MessageBox.Show(Form1.Width); Is this a bad idea somehow?

Comment: Can you post the code for your class? What you want to do is not necessarily wrong, however it raises red-flags as to “why” your Class needs the “whole” `Form1`. In other words, there is probably a better way to do what you describe and want. Please [edit] your question and post the Class you want to do this in. And explain "why" your Class needs to call the `MessageBox` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1:
Storing the instance in a global variable,

```
public static Form1 frm1;


//Form1 constructor
frm1 = this;
```

e.g.

```
public static Form1 frm1;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    frm1 = this;
    
    MessageBox.Show(Form1.frm1.Width.ToString());
}
```

Example 2:
You need to pass an instance to the class.

```
public class Class1
{
    private Form1 _frm1;
    public Class1(Form1 frm1)
    {
        this._frm1 = frm1;
    }
}
```

e.g.

```
public class Class1
{
    private Form1 _frm1;
    public Class1(Form1 frm1)
    {
        this._frm1 = frm1;
        MessageBox.Show(this._frm1.Width.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried pasting the first code in Form1, and the second code in my class. And changing the names to mine. But frm1 = this; gives 4 errors.

Comment: The two examples are different code. Added code.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working now. This is what I was after. =)